# Why Home button get a grey hover too?

Tags: html, css

I would like to make an HTML page which contains a slideshow. I used bootstrap for the menu and I find a slideshow code somewhere on the internet. My problem is that I don't understand why my home button gets a grey hover too. I find the part of the CSS code which does this, but I don't know why and how could I corrigate it. Thank you for your help.

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  background: #f1f1f1f1;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: white;
}

.dot-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}


/* Add an italic font style to all quotes */

q {
  font-style: italic;
}

.kep {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.author {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-top: 150px;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}

#cim {
  text-align: center;
}

#lab {
  text-align: right;
  height: 45px;
  border-top: gray solid;
  background-color: #333;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#hatter {
  width: auto;
  height: 120px;
  background-image: url('szeles.jpg');
}

.active,
dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="galeria2.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col" id="hatter"></div>



      <div class=w-100></div>
      <div class="col">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                 </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                         Dropdown
                       </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>



      <div class=w-100></div>
      <div class="col">


        <div class="slideshow-container">

          <div class="mySlides">

            <div class="cim">
              <h1>A tűz</h1>
            </div>

            <img class="kep" src="kezd1.jpg" alt="steak>">

            <p class="author">

              Ez az alapja mindennek, így mi is kültéri a sütögetés legfontosabb alapelemével ezdünk. A grillsütő alján található lyukakkal szabályozzuk a huzatot, nem pedig a hamut kaparjuk ki rajta. Állítsuk szinkronba a grill tetején lévő szellőzővel! Begyújtás
              előtt az alsó szellőzőt nyissuk ki a maximum állásra, hogy siettessük a parazsat és hamarabb megélénkülhessen.Ha egyenletesen izzik a parazsunk, akkor alul-felül a felére zárjuk a szellőzőnyílást, így csökkentjük a hőt, hiszen nem megégetni
              szeretnénk a húsokat és a zöldségeket, hanem szépen meggrillezni.
            </p>


          </div>

          <div class="mySlides">

            <div class="cim">
              <h1>Faszén</h1>
            </div>

            <img class="kep" src="kezd2.jpg" alt="steak>">

            <p class="author">

              Ne direkt a zsákból öntsük ki, hanem kézzel, egyenletesen eloszlatva rakjuk a ütőre. Gyújtsuk meg a szén közé rakott préselt papírkockákat, majd helyezzük vissza a rostélyt is. Fontos, hogy a rostély együtt forrósodjon fel a grillel, ne utólag rakjuk
              azt a már meleg parázsra. A tetőt a grillre visszahelyezve és a felső szellőzőket teljesen kinyitva nagyjából 20-30 perc elegendő ahhoz, hogy átmelegedjen a grillsütőnk, és izzó parazsunk legyen.
            </p>


          </div>

          <div class="mySlides">

            <div class="cim">
              <h1>Pác</h1>
            </div>

            <img class="kep" src="kezd3.jpg" alt="steak>">

            <p class="author">

              Az előre bepácolt húsokra öntsünk egy pici olajat, és még a tálban forgassuk t őket – a parázs felett viszont semmi esetre se locsoljunk már olajat a húsokra, mert abból csak felesleges füst, tűz és korom lesz. Mindig azokkal a húsokkal kezdjük a grillezést,
              melyek picit nehezebben sülnek, tehát a vastagabb, csontosabb részekkel. A csirkének adjunk pár perc egérutat a legvégére hagyott zöldségekkel szemben. Utolsó mozzanatként őrölt borssal ízesítsük a frissensülteket.
            </p>


          </div>


          <div class="mySlides">

            <div class="cim">
              <h1>Sült zöldségek</h1>
            </div>

            <img class="kep" src="kezd4.jpg" alt="steak>">

            <p class="author"> Egy keverőtálba rakjunk minden olyan zöldséget, amit zeretnénk meggrillezni (paprikát, cukkinit, hagymát, padlizsánt, burgonyát), sózzuk és cukrozzuk is kicsit őket, majd jöhet az olaj.
            </p>


          </div>

          <div class="mySlides">

            <div class="cim">
              <h1>Öntetek, marinádok</h1>
            </div>

            <img class="kep" src="kezd5.jpg" alt="steak>">

            <p class="author"> Olívaolajból, reszelt citromhéjból és fokhagymából, rissen vágott petrezselyemből extrém mennyiségű borssal és sóval összekeverve készítsünk vinaigrette-öntetet az eddigre már megsülő ételeinkhez, illetve salátáinkhoz. Tálaláshoz vágjunk fel
              egy kis salátát, friss idény- zöldséget, és arra is öntsünk a marinádból. Egy friss, vegyes saláta mindig remek kiegészítője lehet a grilles ételeknek.
            </p>


          </div>

          <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
          <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

        </div>

        <div class="dot-container">
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
        </div>

        <script>
          var slideIndex = 1;
          showSlides(slideIndex);

          function plusSlides(n) {
            showSlides(slideIndex += n);
          }

          function currentSlide(n) {
            showSlides(slideIndex = n);
          }

          function showSlides(n) {
            var i;
            var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
            var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
            if (n > slides.length) {
              slideIndex = 1
            }
            if (n < 1) {
              slideIndex = slides.length
            }
            for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
              slides[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
              dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
            dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
          }
        </script>







      </div>



      <div class=w-100></div>
      <div class="col">

        <div id="lab">
          <audio id="player" style="float:left" preload="auto" autoplay controls>
                     <source src="majka.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
          <h3> © Cser Gábor</h3>
        </div>

      </div>




    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There were a few extra `>`'s in your HTML. I removed them. Did that solve the issue?

Comment: @AryeEidelman Please do not edit the code of questions. If it was causing the problem, we have a specific close reason for typos.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove .active class from your Home button class.

```css
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0;
     }
 
     .slideshow-container {
         position: relative;
         background: #f1f1f1f1;
       }
 
       .mySlides {
         display: none;
         padding: 80px;
         text-align: center;
       }
 
       .prev, .next {
         cursor: pointer;
         position: absolute;
         top: 50%;
         width: auto;
         margin-top: -30px;
         padding: 16px;
         color: #888;
         font-weight: bold;
         font-size: 20px;
         border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
         user-select: none;
       }
 
 
       .next {
         position: absolute;
         right: 0;
         border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
       }
       
       /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
       .prev:hover, .next:hover {
         background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
         color: white;
       }
 
       .dot-container {
         text-align: center;
         padding: 20px;
         background: #ddd;}
 
         .dot {
             cursor: pointer;
             height: 15px;
             width: 15px;
             margin: 0 2px;
             background-color: #bbb;
             border-radius: 50%;
             display: inline-block;
             transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
           }
 
         
           
           
           /* Add an italic font style to all quotes */
           q {font-style: italic;}
           
 
           .kep
 
     {
 
       float: right;
       
       width: 25%;
       margin-top: 150px;
       margin-bottom: 150px;
       margin-right: 100px;
       
       
     }
 
     .author
 
     {
     width: 50%;
       text-align: justify;
       
       margin-top: 150px;
       color: black;
       margin-bottom: 150px;
     }
 
     #cim
 
     {
     text-align: center;
 
     }
 
     #lab
 
     {
        
         text-align: right;
        height: 45px;
         border-top: gray solid;
        
         background-color: #333;
         background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
 
     }
 
     #hatter
 
     {
 
         width: auto;
         height: 120px;
         background-image: url('szeles.jpg');
     }
 
     .active, dot:hover {
         background-color: #717171;
       }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="galeria2.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     </head>
         <title>Document</title>
     </head>
     <body>
         
         <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col" id="hatter"></div>
 
         
 
         <div class=w-100 ></div>
         <div class="col">
             <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
 aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
 aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                 </button>
               
                 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                   <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                     <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                       <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
 aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                         Dropdown
                       </a>
                       <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                         <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                       </div>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                       <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                     </li>
                   </ul>
                   <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                     <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                     <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                   </form>
                 </div>
               </nav>
         </div>
 
       
 
         <div class=w-100 ></div>
         <div class="col">
        
 
      <div class="slideshow-container">
 
         <div class="mySlides">
           
           <div class="cim"><h1>A tűz</h1></div>
 
           <img class="kep" src="kezd1.jpg" alt="steak>">
           
           <p class="author"> 
 
             Ez az alapja mindennek, így mi is kültéri a sütögetés legfontosabb alapelemével kezdünk. A grillsütő alján található
 lyukakkal szabályozzuk a huzatot, nem pedig a hamut kaparjuk ki rajta.
 Állítsuk szinkronba a grill tetején lévő szellőzővel! Begyújtás előtt
 az alsó szellőzőt nyissuk ki a maximum állásra, hogy siettessük a
 parazsat és hamarabb megélénkülhessen.Ha egyenletesen izzik a
 parazsunk, akkor alul-felül a felére zárjuk a szellőzőnyílást, így
 csökkentjük a hőt, hiszen nem megégetni szeretnénk a húsokat és a
 zöldségeket, hanem szépen meggrillezni.
           </p>
        
        
           </div>
         
         <div class="mySlides">
           
           <div class="cim"><h1>Faszén</h1></div>
 
           <img class="kep" src="kezd2.jpg" alt="steak>">
           
           <p class="author"> 
            
             Ne direkt a zsákból öntsük ki, hanem kézzel, egyenletesen eloszlatva rakjuk a sütőre. Gyújtsuk meg a szén közé rakott préselt
 papírkockákat, majd helyezzük vissza a rostélyt is. Fontos, hogy a
 rostély együtt forrósodjon fel a grillel, ne utólag rakjuk azt a már
 meleg parázsra. A tetőt a grillre visszahelyezve és a felső
 szellőzőket teljesen kinyitva nagyjából 20-30 perc elegendő ahhoz,
 hogy átmelegedjen a grillsütőnk, és izzó parazsunk legyen.
           </p>
        
        
           </div>
         
           <div class="mySlides">
           
             <div class="cim"><h1>Pác</h1></div>
       
             <img class="kep" src="kezd3.jpg" alt="steak>">
             
             <p class="author"> 
              
               Az előre bepácolt húsokra öntsünk egy pici olajat, és még a tálban forgassuk át őket – a parázs felett viszont semmi esetre
 se locsoljunk már olajat a húsokra, mert abból csak felesleges füst,
 tűz és korom lesz. Mindig azokkal a húsokkal kezdjük a grillezést,
 melyek picit nehezebben sülnek, tehát a vastagabb, csontosabb
 részekkel. A csirkének adjunk pár perc egérutat a legvégére hagyott
 zöldségekkel szemben. Utolsó mozzanatként őrölt borssal ízesítsük a
 frissensülteket.
             </p>
          
          
             </div>
 
 
             <div class="mySlides">
           
               <div class="cim"><h1>Sült zöldségek</h1></div>
         
               <img class="kep" src="kezd4.jpg" alt="steak>">
               
               <p class="author"> Egy keverőtálba rakjunk minden olyan zöldséget, amit szeretnénk meggrillezni (paprikát, cukkinit, hagymát,
 padlizsánt, burgonyát), sózzuk és cukrozzuk is kicsit őket, majd jöhet
 az olaj.
               </p>
            
            
               </div>
 
               <div class="mySlides">
           
                 <div class="cim"><h1>Öntetek, marinádok</h1></div>
           
                 <img class="kep" src="kezd5.jpg" alt="steak>">
                 
                 <p class="author"> Olívaolajból, reszelt citromhéjból és fokhagymából, frissen vágott petrezselyemből extrém mennyiségű
 borssal és sóval összekeverve készítsünk vinaigrette-öntetet az
 eddigre már megsülő ételeinkhez, illetve salátáinkhoz. Tálaláshoz
 vágjunk fel egy kis salátát, friss idény- zöldséget, és arra is
 öntsünk a marinádból. Egy friss, vegyes saláta mindig remek
 kiegészítője lehet a grilles ételeknek.
                 </p>
              
              
                 </div>
         
         <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
         <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
         
         </div>
         
         <div class="dot-container">
           <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
           <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
           <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
           <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span> 
           <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span> 
         </div>
 
     <script>
     var slideIndex = 1;
     showSlides(slideIndex);
 
     function plusSlides(n) {
       showSlides(slideIndex += n);
     }
 
     function currentSlide(n) {
       showSlides(slideIndex = n);
     }
 
     function showSlides(n) {
       var i;
       var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
       var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
       if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
       if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
       for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
           slides[i].style.display = "none";  
       }
       for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
           dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
       }
       slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
       dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
     }
     </script>
 
 
 
        
             
            
 
     </div>
 
 
 
     <div class=w-100 ></div>
         <div class="col">
             
             <div id="lab">
                 <audio id="player" style="float:left" preload="auto" autoplay controls>
                     <source src="majka.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
                         <h3> © Cser Gábor</h3>
             </div>
            
             </div>
 
 
 
 
         </div>
 
 
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: thank you so much it works. i have an other and final question. why i can't use the dropdown menu button? when i click it not dorp down and i can't see the submenus

Comment: it requires JavaScript plugin If JavaScript is disabled and the viewport is narrow enough that the navbar collapses, it will be impossible to expand the navbar and view the content within the .navbar-collapse.

Comment: @GáborCser you also need to include the Bootstrap JS for the dropdown to work. https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Please make sure you are added the bootstrap.js and jquary.js into your HTML file.